# How can change application font in runtime?

Tags: c#

how can change my app font in runtime? my app have MDI form and child form and i want change app font in main form (MDI form) and save in setting. but when change font, not effect in menu and contorl.

```
fontDialog1.ShowDialog();
Font = fontDialog1.Font;
```

also i add this code for change all control in main form.

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
{
    c.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
}
```

but this effect in current form and do not change child form.
than in add this code for change child font when show

```
public FrmChild()
{
    font = myfont;
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        c.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
    }
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Try this foreach loop code below initializecomponent() call.

Comment: The child controls should "inherit" the form's Font property to bring this to a good end.  So iterating the Controls collection is not necessary, just change the form's Font.   If you see a control not resize and/or change its font then right-click its Font property and click Reset.  You are asking about the MdiChildren property, you'll have to iterate it as well to get the child forms to change.  Do avoid adding bells and whistles that are not actually useful, getting a messed-up layout is a very likely mishap here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 FontDialog fd = new FontDialog();
            fd.ShowDialog();
            Settings.Default.MyFont = fd.Font;
            Settings.Default.Save();
            Font = Settings.Default.MyFont;
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                c.Font = Settings.Default.MyFont;
            }
```